# Where can I find a Forth / Gforth API?

Tags: forth, gforth

Is something like [the Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) or comprehensive manual of all already implemented methods for Forth?

Comment: Other Forth books of interest (all freely available) may be Leo Brodie's *[Thinking Forth](http://thinking-forth.sourceforge.net/)* (another book from the same author), Stephen Pelc's *[Programming Forth](http://www.mpeforth.com/arena/ProgramForth.pdf)* (PDF), Philip J. Koopman's *[Stack Computers: the new wave](http://www.ece.cmu.edu/~koopman/stack%5Fcomputers/contents.html)*, and Tim Hendtlass's *[Real Time Forth](ftp://ftp.taygeta.com/pub/Forth/Literature/rtfv5.pdf)* (PDF).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a single source defining/describing Forth words (*methods*) because different implementations of Forth have different sets of implemented words. Not only do different Forth implementations include different words, but the behavior of the words may be different across the different implementations. Several Forth standards have been specified including FIG Forth, Forth-79, Forth-83, and ANSI Forth (1994). You can find a copy of the ANSI Forth specification at http://lars.nocrew.org/dpans/dpans.htm.

Gforth is a specific Forth implementation and is compatible with the ANS Forth standard. You can find more information including a manual with a glossary of defined words at http://www.gnu.org/software/gforth/.

Comment: Recommendations for learning resources [are off-topic for stackoverflow.com Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). However, this information [could be ok as part of a tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214338/997587).

Answer (score 3):

You can find a wordlist of a gforth-installation under **doc/gforth/Word-Index.html**
Some of the predefinied words have also examples.

Answer (score 1):

As @Matthew said, words and their behaviour vary across different implementations. For Gforth I'd suggest [the user manual](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/).  At least that's way I learned Forth along with the brilliant [Starting Forth](http://www.forth.com/starting-forth/).  [ANS Forth specification](http://www.forth.com/downloads/dpans94.pdf) may come in handy too.

Also if you're not happy with current implementations, believe me, it's not that difficult to write your own Forth :-)

Comment: Good point re writing your own Forth! Even if you don't intend to, http://git.annexia.org/?p=jonesforth.git;a=summary is a good read.